# In Cucumber Is there a way to reorder test Scenarios during a test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, scenarios

Sorry if this question sounds dumb, still learning new ways of improving my tests.

Say I am running a random parallel test on 4 threads and a new scenario B is to be started on thread 4 but thread 2 already has a test scenario A running that shares a resource that is locked during the test. Is there a way to get the next scenario in line and push scenario B back one on the queue? (possibly using the scenario @ tags)

Is there a way to access the test lineup directly during the test to manipulate it like this?

Let me know if I should give any more info or a clearer statement on it.

I have Investigated it for a few days myself as well as searching here to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There is no dumb question, but yours need more precisions. In particular you must show us what you have tried so far and not expect people do the work.

Comment: Are you using Cucumber with JUnit 5? If so, see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#exclusive-resources but there are some limitations inherited from JUnit.

Comment: we are using Cucumber Selenium. I had tried researching it for quite a while but have not figured out where the list of tests are or how to access them, I have not found anyone who has made any attempt to access it either. While I have spent quite a while on it, there really is not any fruits of my efforts to show sadly, I do apologize for that, but would appreciate some hints or examples of how to manipulate this.